# If $f$ is bijective but undefined at a point, is it a function?

Tags: functions, notation

Consider the set $A = \{x \in \mathbb{Z{\ge_0}}$ and $x \in {-2}\}, B = \{f(x)\}$.

Is $f: A \to B$ still a bijection even though $f(-2)$ is undefined?

Comment: Try the command `\text{ and }` to insert a text "and" in math mode. Or use `\land` (logical and) in math mode for a $\land$.

Comment: I'm still confused as to the actual question. Is $A$ a set? A function? If the latter, what is its domain? And what does $x \in -2$ mean exactly? If you're looking for curly braces to help define a set, try `\{` and `\}` in math mode.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  What are the two sets that you claim are in bijection?  What is the proposed bijection between them?

Comment: @TheoBendit see edit

Comment: @lulu see edit.

Comment: What does $B=\{f(x)\}$ mean?  What does $x\in -2$ mean?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a triple ($f, A, B$) where $f \subseteq A \times B$ satisfying certain properties. So what you should really be asking is, *is $f$ a bijection between A and B*?
If $f(-2)$ is not defined, this means that $-2 \notin A$, so it doesn't have any consequence on whether your function is a bijection between A and B or not.